# Redirecting a page to the same page under a different domain

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am changing domain names and want to set up a structure like so:

If a user accesses **www.olddomain.com/page**, he will be re-directed to **www.newdomain.com/page**, etc. In other words, only the pre-slash part of the domain would change. I want to do this for all pages under the old domain.

Does anyone know how I can configure this?

Comment: I can do this with PHP - I'm not sure you can do this directly with apache unless both domains are hosted on the same server, in which case look into [rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: How would you do it with PHP?

Comment: I think the solution posted by Jon Lin below is more eloquent (although I haven't tried it myself) - if you still want my PHP solution let me know and I'll clean the code up and post it - it basically involves redirecting all pages on your old site to index.php, which then issues a header("Location:") by simply replacing the part of the path before the first / with your new domain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can do this a number of ways in the htaccess file in the document root *of your old domain*. If the old and new domains are on different servers, or at least different document roots, then you can simply use mod_alias' redirect:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/
```

If you have some confusion about sharing folders between the domains or they reside in the same document root, you'll need to check the HTTP HOST field and use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Looks great. What if I needed it go from https://olddomain.com/page to https://newdomain.com/page?

Comment: @JohnRoberts the first mod_alias directive automatically includes everything after the slash in the new domain, the second mod_rewrite rule backreferences the request using `$1`. So whatever after the `/` gets included in both instances

Comment: No, what I mean is, what if I don't want the "www" in front?

Comment: @JohnRoberts then just remove it from the rules

Comment: I find that this only worked for re-directing olddomain.com to newdomain.com, but not olddomain.com/page to newdomain.com/page. Both sites use WordPress - could that have something to do with why it didn't work?

Comment: @JohnRoberts looking at your new question, you must put all redirect rules before your wordpress rules, otherwise the wordpress rule will simply rewrite everything you want to redirect.