# .htaccess wordpress multisite redirect between subsites

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am building a new site for a client. we preserved the old site in a wordpress multisitesolution. Now it's time to migrate into the new site. Problem is the old site is heavilly embedded in Google Search with many active links. So I need a way to catch and redirect each and every link that comes our way.

I can redirect old.sitename.com to new.sitename.com directly - this works fine. Problem is when I get direct links to posts or pages.

Som this is the syntax I need resolved

old.sitename.com/an-article-read-this --> new.sitename.com/an-article-read-this

I have tried several .htaccess commands, including a few wordpress addons. Even simple ssl with .htaccess redirect enabled.

```
RewriteRule ^old.*$\% https://hoppla.heiledeg.no/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

direct links keeps opening up in the old site. not the new one.
Yes I have refreshed cache. And even tested on "fresh" browsers.

Any ideas, tips, or even addons are very much appreciated.

Comment: RewriteRule matches against the _path_ component of the requested URL only. You need a RewriteCond to check what the requested host name was.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting a page to the same page under a different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735697/redirecting-a-page-to-the-same-page-under-a-different-domain)

Answer (score 0):

for me this was the solution:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(old.)?olddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]